# Relationship without marriage

Tags: halal-haram, nikah, relationships

First of all, Assalamu Alaikum

I am a Muslim guy and I have been in a long distance relationship with this athiest girl for 4 years now, I told her that I intend to marry her in the future but she'll have to convert to Muslim for that.

I've learned that a Muslim man can only marry a woman from one of the three abrahamic religions, She used to be a Christian and left the religion because she's had very terrible experiences because of it.

I've tried my absolute best to convince her and explain to her what our religion is but she does not want to convert.

I love her too much and I do not want to leave her. We've discussed this for weeks now, but we didn't come to a conclusion.

Now my question is, Can we go for a live in relationship without marriage? I know that physical relations are Haraam before marriage and I do not intend to touch her that way.

Thank you for your time.